# Backbone Event functions unable to access changed object that caused the event

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

Here is a little backboneJS program - written in Typescript - where I am trying to trigger various functions based on changes in the data in the model. While the function gets triggered, I'm having a hard time getting the triggered function to be able to access the model instance which has been changed (added, deleted, modified etc.) causing the event. In this little program, I've made a little API call `e.change.get("answer")` which I'm pretty sure is wrong, but I'm unable to find the right API call.

```
class Answers extends Backbone.Collection {

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        var self = this;
        this.on("add", function (e) {
            console.log("Added a new answer : " + e.change.get("answer")); // Need to access the newly added answer instance here
        }, this);
    }

    model = Answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access it with

```
    this.on("add", function (model) {
        console.log("Added a new answer : " + model);
    });
```

The first argument is the model  (see http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

Comment: If the answer is correct, please accept it so other users can find correct answers easily.